# How to execute a script when application is terminated

Tags: 16.04, scripts, .desktop

To execute a script when application starts, I can change the `Exec` directive in `/usr/share/applications/App.desktop`

What about when application closes? Is there any hook for that event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use something like

   ```
   Exec=bash -c 'do-before;do-main-task;do-after'
   ```

   in your desktop file. **do-after** should do what you want to do 
   'after the application closes'. It can be a shell-script. I use this method and it works for me, but it can be tricky because of the quoting.
2. You can also put your application in a bash shell-script that will do all the tasks for you (call your application from the script), and put the name of the script in the Exec line in the desktop file.

   ```
   Exec=do-all-tasks-script
   ```

   This method is more likely to work, if the tasks contain complicated syntax (and might not work 'inside quotes').

It is a correct remark by Serg, that you should not edit the system files. I guess this is a special case, and you can copy the desktop file to the desktop, and edit this copy. (I make this kind of desktop files for my own applications.)

**Extra**

I made the following batch file 'dbdmda'

```
#!/bin/bash

echo do-before
transmission-gtk
echo do-after
```

and ran it like this: When transmission started I let it run for approximately ten seconds. Then I exited from transmission by pressing the x button in the top right corner. This was written to the terminal window

```
$ bash dbdmda 
do-before
do-after
```

So obviously the 'do-after' command line was run. How are you calling transmission, and how is it stopped?

Comment: Is it ok to add an `Exec` entry __before__ and __after__ the _applications launch_ entry in the `.desktop` files will that achieve his aim also.

Comment: I have never tried more than one Exec entry in a desktop file. It does not bite, so you dare try - maybe it works :-) Sorry, do you ask 'Is it?' or state 'It is'?

Comment: 'Is it', just thinking I'll try to see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks sudodus. I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work. The do-after script was never called.

Comment: What application is it, and what did you write in the Exec line?

Comment: sudodus, I'm trying to run a script when Transmission shuts down. It's is a one liner bash script (for testing purposes) which creates a file in my home directory (using touch). My do-before and do-main (which is the launch of Transmission) are also sitting in  a bash script and they work fine.

Comment: What happens if you 'do the do-after task' in the script with transmission? It should work unless transmission will shut down in a way that kills the script instead of exiting and leaving control back to the script. See what I tried in an 'extra' paragraph of my main answer.

Comment: Hi sudodus, your solution worked when I've placed all the pieces inside a single script as oppose to placing the do-after in the Exec directive. So now I have:  #!/bin/bash  do-before  transmission-gtk $@  do-after .  Thank you.

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad you have a working desktop file + script now :-)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's generally considered a bad practice to edit files in `/usr/share/applications`. In addition, it's highly inefficient, because it comes as part of a package, and if there's update to that package, guess what ? Your changes will be overwritten. If you absolutely, 100%, need to make changes, make a custom `.desktop` file and store it in `~/.local/share/applications`

Instead, I would recommend using a script that uses `while` loops and `pgrep -f` to wait for the app you want. For example, in the example below , the script uses `firefox` as process string.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

process_string="firefox"
while true
do

    while ! pgrep -f "$process_string"
    do
       echo "Waiting for $process_string"
       sleep 3
    done

    while pgrep -f "$process_string"
    do
       echo "Waiting for $process_string to exit"
       sleep 3
    done

    # place the command you want to occur when 
    # process exits here
sleep 3
done
```

The script runs in continuous loop so you could add it as part of Startup Applications to launch upon logging in

Comment: Thanks Serg. I've created a local copy inside ~/.local/share/applications as per your advise. I will give you script a go and will report back.

Comment: Hi Serg, I've tried your solution and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user634037 wonderful ! Consider taking time to mark this post as accepted ( grey checkmark next to the up / down arrows)